# Calling nested function using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code which calls a function test() on  body onload

```
<body onLoad="test();">
```

The Test function has 2 more functions drawLayers() ,StopAll().

```
function test() {

  function drawLayers() {
   timers = [];
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawMoon,800));
       timers.push(setTimeout(drawCircle1,2300));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawCircle2,2700));
    timers.push(setTimeout(drawCircle3,3100));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawCircle4,3500));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawCircle5,3900));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext2,4300));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext,4700));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext3,5100));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext4,5500));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext5,5900));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext6,6300));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext7,6700));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext8,7100));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext9,7500));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawtext10,7900));



    }

 function StopAll() {
     alert('fsdfsdf');
        for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++)
             window.clearTimeout(timers[i]);
    }
}
```

What i want to do is  Call the StopAL() function on click of a button, the html code looks like below

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="StopAll();">
```

Its throwing error, "StopAll is not defined"

How do i call the StopALL() function?

Answer (score 5):

The scope of those nested functions is restricted to the `test` function only. You cannot invoke them from the outside. If you need to do that you could externalize it from the `test` function.

Answer (score 4):

This is a 'closure' problem. The function `StopAll` is within the scope of the `test` function, and therefore is undefined in the global scope in which you are trying to call it.

Closures are a tricky subject to grasp initially. There's a good explanation here:
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

(by the way `StopAll` should really be called `stopAll` because capitalised functions are generally reserved for use with the `new` keyword.)

Answer (score 3):

```
test = function (){

  this.drawLayers = function() {
        this.timers = [];
        this.timers.push(setTimeout(drawMoon,800));       
    }

  this.StopAll = function() {
       alert('fsdfsdf');
        var t = timers.length
        for (var i = 0; i < t; i++)
             window.clearTimeout(this.timers[i]);
    }
}

 var testObj =  new test();
 testObj.StopAll()
```

Comment: You should add a description to your answer, rather than just posting code.

Answer (score 2):

```
function test() {

    function drawLayers() {
        timers = [];
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawMoon,800));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawCircle1,2300));
        timers.push(setTimeout(drawCircle2,2700));
    }

    var StopAll=function() {
        alert('fsdfsdf');
        for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++)
            window.clearTimeout(timers[i]);
    }
    return StopAll;
}
var obj= new test();
//to call StopAll function
obj();
```

Comment: it works good but i takes 2 sec to execute that func. too late

Answer (score 1):

```
(function test($) {
  function drawLayers() {  
  }
  //expose this to outside world ,public function
  $.StopAll = function() {
    alert('fsdfsdf');
  }
})(window);

StopAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better not use html attributes to bind event handler, you can do the same with the following code:

```
    window.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function(){
        StopAll();    
      }    
    }


  // Your functions
```

This way you'll ensure your dom is loaded and ready to call event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the function StopAll() outside the test function and call it as specified. If suppose you need to access that function even in the test(), you can do like this

```
function test() {

.....
drawLayers();
StopAll() ;

}

function StopAll() {
     alert('fsdfsdf');
        for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++)
             window.clearTimeout(timers[i]);
    }
```

Declaration of function can be given outside and called any where you want